# Can we create database by SSDT package?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, .net-5, c#-9.0

I am using Visual Studio 2019 I installed the SSDT tool I created a DB project. But my requirement is that I need to create different sql database for each client. Is it possible by Using SSDT package. I only create table, stored procedure, functions, views etc. but not Database.
Please provide me a way to develop it. Is there any Azure API by which we can create database for each client?.

Comment: You can control the database name in the publish/deploy options so it can go to the appropriate database. You'd write up your code, generate a dacpac, and publish that to each database as needed.  Not sure about the Azure APIs to publish a dacpac automatically, but there should be some options.

Comment: thanks @PeterSchott but I want to create a new DB on click of submit button.

Comment: That should be doable, but you'll need to do some coding for that. The APIs probably aren't "Azure" specific, though you might need some Azure calls to make sure there's a server/database ready to receive the dacpac structure.  If the database already exists, you'll need something for the connect string and appropriate rights for each database to make those changes.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterSchott I will dig it more in the same direction as you suggested.